# Ruby Syntax error only says "unexpected '\n', expecting =>

Tags: ruby

I desperately need to understand what the problem with this code is, and as usual I somehow am getting a syntax error message *nobody* has ever gotten before when trying to code something as simple as a while loop with conditionals in it:
    syntax error, unexpected '\n', expecting =>

I know there is another SO question that asked about that, but the issue is the other code involved hashes and things that I am not using - all I'm trying to do here is read in a number and generate one of a set of responses based on that input. But never in my life has a program just up and refused to even specify what I need to do!

This is my code, :

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

time=-1

while (time < 0)

    print "Enter the total number of minutes you spend per week reading/studying: ",
    time => gets.to_i

    if (time >= 120)
    {
    puts => "Congratulations! You will likely pass the course."
    }
    elsif (time > -1)
    {
            if (time > 60)
            {
            puts=>"OK...You may still pass the course."
            }
            else
            {
            puts=>"I have grave concerns about your study habits."
}end 
end
```

I try to run this and all it ever tells me is it expects "=>" somehow. And if the end bit isn't exactly "}end end" then Ruby freaks out and tells me I have unexpected "}" where it expects "keyword_end" but then when I change it, the thing immediately tells me it doesn't expect the keyword_end instances *it literally just told me to put in* and it expects the brackets *it told me to remove*

And I WOULD have the entire thing wrapped in brackets for the while loop, but THEN this thing freaks out by insisting there isn't a closing bracket where the first "if" statement is.

So fed up with this, been trying for hours and I'm ready to give up because Ruby's error messages are the most unhelpful things I've ever come across!

Comment: Ruby doesn't use brackets...

Comment: I do not recognise this as Ruby code... this needs a complete rewrite.

Comment: What is the `=>` in `time => gets.to_i` meant to do? What is the `=>` in `puts => ...` meant to do? It seems like you're just throwing `=>` in everywhere without understanding what it does. (Hint: It's only used for hashes, and you don't have any hashes in your code.)

Comment: And @Tico is partly right. Curly braces are used in Ruby (for hashes and blocks), but they're not used for `if` expressions. They are not correct in your code.

Comment: I'm not sure what help you're expecting Ruby to give you here. You're using curly braces and hashrockets (`=>`) in ways that are completely foreign to Ruby. It's like writing the word "orange" in the middle of a musician's score and getting mad when they can neither play it nor tell you what you should have written instead.

Comment: Ya, I think this is purely syntax issues. I didn't really check your logic because you need to fix your syntax. Just look up Ruby `while` loops, fix the while loop. Then look up Ruby `if` statements, and fix those as well. Then you should be able to see the problem more clearly (if there is one with the logic)

Comment: Yeah, just removed the brackets and now I have it working the loop. I'm so used to using them I didn't realize Ruby didn't function that way. Kinda wish it did, though, it kept code blocks easier to read for me. Thanks to everyone for responding, though, now I know how not to waste time in the future.

Comment: You'll find that consistent indentation and judicious whitespace will make Ruby code as readable as any, as in @sagarpandya82's answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Correcting your code:

```
print "Enter the total number of minutes you spend per week reading/studying: "
time = gets.to_i

if time >= 120
  puts "Congratulations! You will likely pass the course."
elsif time > 60
  puts "OK...You may still pass the course."
else
  puts "I have grave concerns about your study habits."
end
```

Study how this is written and you should be ok.